# Android VolleyError retrieve requested URL

Tags: android, url, error-handling, android-volley

I am using volley library to do some API request. I have a BaseError class and a BaseRequest class, but now i need to retrieve the URL, when i get a response. To not go request by request and set the URL there, I would like to retrieve the requested URL by VolleyError object.

How can i get the URL I am looking for?

BaseError:

```
public abstract class BaseError implements Response.ErrorListener {

private Context mContext;

protected BaseError(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    String errorDesc;

    if (error.networkResponse == null) {
        if (!Connectivity.isConnected(mContext)) {
            errorDesc = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.error_internet_connection);
        } else {
            errorDesc = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.error_unexpected);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN) {
                errorDesc = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.error_authorization);
            } else {
                String dataStr = new String(error.networkResponse.data);
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(dataStr);
                Timber.e(object.optString("message"));
                errorDesc = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.error_unexpected);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            errorDesc = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.error_unexpected);
        }
    }

    onError(new ErrorResponse(errorDesc, error), "url missing here...");
}

public abstract void onError(ErrorResponse response, String url);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer i found for this was to change the `VolleyError` object, by adding:

```
private String mUrl;

public void setUrl(String url){
    this.mUrl = url;
}

public String getUrl(){
    return mUrl;
}
```

Than on BaseRequest class override the method `deliverError()`:

```
@Override
public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    error.setUrl(getUrl());
    listenerError.onErrorResponse(error);
}
```

Now on `BaseError` you have access to the URL inside the `VolleyError` object:

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    error.getUrl(); //here it is
    //....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could have tried this in your `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)` method:

```
String url = error.networkResponse.headers.get("Referer");
```

`VolleyError` has a [NetworkResponse](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/com/android/volley/NetworkResponse.java) object attached that has information about the original request.

Comment: it returns null. I don't have the key "Referer".

Comment: Also return null, the key "Referer" does not exist