# Android Volley get redirect url

Tags: android, android-volley

I need to get redirected url from Volley response: in my case the last redirected url returns 404, but I can't figure out how can I get the url from `VolleyError`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630993/android-volleyerror-retrieve-requested-url volleyerror object

Comment: Check the response header from your web service to see if it has "Location" value or not? Can you try with some tool such as Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Design your server to add URL in the header when sending a response back to the client after that you can get the header from the VolleyError

```
      NetworkResponse response = volleyError.networkResponse;

      if (response != null && response.data != null) {
           Map<String, String> headers = response.headers;
           String URL = headers.get("my_url_key");
      }
```

Or alternately everytime you do some request you can overide the `getHeaders()` e.g.

```
      JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    createURL(), null, success, errorListener) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                    header.put("my_url_key", "http://mywebsite.com");
                    return header;
                }
      };
```

The retrieval is the same as the above code but much more convenient since you will no longer need to change anything at your server.

If you want to perform the redirection based on the response code you can do the following:

```
 NetworkResponse response = volleyError.networkResponse;

 if (response != null && response.data != null) {
       if(response.statusCode == 404){
           // Do something here
       }
 }
```

Lets just hope that the server will include the redirection URL along with the binary response.

Ex.

```
  NetworkResponse response = volleyError.networkResponse;

     if (response != null && response.data != null) {
           JSONObject o = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
           // get the info here
     }
```

Comment: I can't change the server

Comment: I like this approach, but how can I get redirected url and put it to the header?

Comment: @konopko As far as I know you cannot get it unless your server send it along with the header. IMO a good server design must always also add the redirection site. e.g `{ "errorcode":111, "redirect":"example.com", "message":"File not Found!" }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in my case the server do not retrieve a URL in both headers and data